# raise exception after 5 records for Oracle Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm having problem some problem with oracle trigger and hope you guys can help me out here.

A customer can only purchase 5 items for the current month so anything above 5 the trigger will throw an exception.

this is what i've done so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER five_reading
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PURCHASE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    totover NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (custID)
    INTO   totover
    FROM   PURCHASE
    WHERE :NEW.custID = PURCHASE.custID
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM :NEW.datevisited)
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM :NEW.datevisited);  
    IF totover = 5  THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20001, 
        'Customer' || :NEW.custID ||
        ' already has 5 purchases' );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

However i'm still unable to insert new records when the customer has less then 5 purchases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - in the question you say that the customer "...can only purchase 5 items for the current month so anything above 5 the trigger will throw an exception", but the trigger throws an exception only if the customer has made exactly five purchases.

Try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER five_reading
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PURCHASE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  totover NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   totover
  FROM   PURCHASE p
  WHERE p.custid = :NEW.custid AND
        TRUNC(p.datevisited, 'MONTH') = TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH');
  IF totover > 5  THEN
    COMMIT;  -- autonomous transaction

    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20001, 
                             'Customer' || :NEW.custID ||
                             ' already has ' || totover || ' purchases' );
  END IF;

  COMMIT;  -- autonomous transaction
END;
```

Also, you don't say what happens after the above exception is raised. When this exception is caught you should roll the outer transaction back.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: thanks for the highlight. I've just realized that too. But now I'm having the issue that I'm not able to insert any new data even though the customer has less then 5 purchase. It will throw me the same error message.

Comment: What message? I think you must have commit or rollback at the end of the autonomous transaction

Comment: the message I'm receiving is 'SQL Error: ORA-20001: Customer103 already has 5 purchases' even though there only 2 purchase made by this customer. I've tried to add the word commit or rollback but nth changes.

Comment: I added COMMITs for the autonomous transaction, and changed the message provided with the exception to include the number of records found. Try that and see what occurs.

Comment: oh, that's a good way to do debugging. I've tried the solution and it gives me the total number of transaction for the year (all above 5). However I would only want to check the transaction for July 2014. any idea why the `TRUNC(:NEW.datevisited, 'MONTH') = TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')` is not having any effect? I've added another line for the year too, but i'm having the same issue too.

Comment: I've corrected the query in the answer. The problem is that `TRUNC(:NEW.DATEVISITED, 'MONTH')` is a constant, only considering the DATEVISITED value from the updated row. So if it's true for that one row, it'll be true for all rows in the table for the given CUSTID. The comparison needs to be as it's now shown in the answer. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis sorry for the trouble I've tried the solution given but i'm still able to insert new record although the the cust has already made 5 purchase. However if i change it to `IF totover = 5` it works, but it doesn't make sense to put it =5.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `totover >= 5`?

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you have discovered, you cannot select from the same table that a row-level trigger is defined against; it causes a table mutating exception. You have attempted to get round this by adding the autonomous transaction pragma. Unfortunately, although this works, it is just covering up your mistake in methodology.

In order to properly create this validation using a trigger a procedure should be created to obtain user-specified locks so the validation can be correctly serialized in a multi-user environment.

```
PROCEDURE request_lock
  (p_lockname                     IN     VARCHAR2
  ,p_lockmode                     IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT dbms_lock.x_mode
  ,p_timeout                      IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 60
  ,p_release_on_commit            IN     BOOLEAN  DEFAULT TRUE
  ,p_expiration_secs              IN     INTEGER  DEFAULT 600)
IS
  -- dbms_lock.allocate_unique issues implicit commit, so place in its own
  -- transaction so it does not affect the caller
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  l_lockhandle                   VARCHAR2(128);
  l_return                       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_lock.allocate_unique
    (lockname                       => p_lockname
    ,lockhandle                     => p_lockhandle
    ,expiration_secs                => p_expiration_secs);
  l_return := dbms_lock.request
    (lockhandle                     => l_lockhandle
    ,lockmode                       => p_lockmode
    ,timeout                        => p_timeout
    ,release_on_commit              => p_release_on_commit);
  IF    (l_return = 1) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Timeout');
  ELSIF (l_return = 2) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Deadlock');
  ELSIF (l_return = 3) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Parameter Error');
  ELSIF (l_return = 5) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Illegal Lock Handle');
  ELSIF (l_return not in (0,4)) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'dbms_lock.request Unknown Return Value ' || l_return);
  END IF;
  -- Must COMMIT an autonomous transaction
  COMMIT;
END request_lock;
```

This procedure can then be used in a compound trigger (assuming at least Oracle 11, this will need to be split into individual triggers in earlier versions)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER too_many_purchases
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON purchase
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  -- Table to hold identifiers of inserted/updated customer purchases
  g_custIDs sys.odcinumberlist;

BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS
BEGIN
-- Reset the internal customer table
  g_custIDs := g_custIDs();
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  -- Store the inserted/updated customers
  IF (  INSERTING
     OR (   UPDATING
        AND (  :new.custID <> :old.custID
            OR (   trunc(:new.dateVisited) = trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
               AND trunc(:old.dateVisited) <> trunc(sysdate, 'MM')))))
  THEN           
    g_custIDs.EXTEND;
    g_custIDs(g_custIDs.LAST) := :new.custID;
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT
IS
  CURSOR csr_customers
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT
           cst.column_value custID
    FROM TABLE(g_custIDs) cid
    ORDER BY cst.column_value;
  CURSOR csr_constraint_violations
    (p_custID   purchase.custID%TYPE)
  IS
    SELECT count(*) purchases
    FROM purchase pch
    WHERE pch.custID = p_custID
    AND trunc(pch.dateVisited, 'MM') = trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
    HAVING count(*) > 5;
  r_constraint_violation csr_constraint_violations%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Check if for any inserted/updated customer purchase there exists more than
  -- 5 purchases for the same customer for the current month. Serialise the
  -- constraint for each custID so concurrent transactions do not affect each
  -- other
  FOR r_customer IN csr_customers LOOP
    request_lock('TOO_MANY_PURCHASES_' || r_customer.custID);
    OPEN csr_constraint_violations(r_customer.custID);
    FETCH csr_constraint_violations INTO r_constraint_violation;
    IF csr_constraint_violations%FOUND THEN
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Customer ' || r_customer.custID || ' now has ' || r_constraint_violation.purchases || ' purchases this month');
    ELSE
      CLOSE csr_constraint_violations;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
```